# When I reload the url useEffect return empty array - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

When we call filterOnClick function it returns the required "fdata".

Console :
[[Prototype]]: Array(2)

0: {filter: 'countries', values: Array(3), search: '', checkedValue: 'india'}

1: {filter: 'states', values: Array(3), search: '', checkedValue: null}, "fdata"
//Required.

But when we reload the  url it returns empty ,
[[Prototype]]: Array(0) [] , "fdata" .

```
// Universities start here
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";

const filterData = {
  data: {
    countries: [
      {
        name: "dubai",
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "canada",
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        name: "india",
        id: 3,
      },
    ],
    states: [
      {
        name: "tamil nadu",
        id: 4,
      },
      {
        name: "kerala",
        id: 5,
      },
      {
        name: "ttk",
        id: 6,
      },
    ],
  },
};

const Universities = () => {
  const [fdata, setFData] = useState([]);
  const [filterTagList, setFilterTagList] = useState([]);
  const { countries } = useParams();
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    Object.entries(filterData?.data).map(([key, values]) => {
      let query = {
        filter: key,
        values: values,
        search: "",
        checkedValue: null,
      };
      setFData((fdata) => [...fdata, query]);
    });
  }, [filterData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCountry();
  }, [countries]);

  const setCountry = () => {
    if (countries) {
      if (fdata.length > 0 && countries) {
        let ind = fdata.findIndex((e) => e.filter === "countries");
        var newStateArray = [...fdata];
        newStateArray[ind].checkedValue = countries;
        setFData(newStateArray);
      }
      console.log(fdata, "fdata");
      let filterTagIndex = filterTagList.findIndex(
        (e) => e.label === "countries"
      );
      if (filterTagIndex >= 0) {
        // exist
        const newState = [...filterTagList];
        newState[filterTagIndex].value = countries;
        setFilterTagList(newState);
      } else {
        // not exist
        setFilterTagList((data) => [
          ...data,
          { label: "countries", value: countries },
        ]);
      }
    }
  };

  const filterOnClick = (event, label) => {
    if (label === "countries") {
      navigate(`/universities/study-in-${event.target.value}`);
    } else {
      navigate(`/universities/study-in-${event.target.value}?state=dubai`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>reload
      {fdata?.map((item, idx) => (
        <Accordion
          className="accordion h-100"
          key={item["filter"]}
          defaultActiveKey={item["filter"]}
        >
          <Accordion.Item
            eventKey={item["filter"]}
            className="accordion-item pb-3"
            key={idx}
          >
            <Accordion.Header
              className="accordion-header"
              id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne"
            >
              {item["filter"]}
            </Accordion.Header>

            <div className="accordion-collapse collapse show">
              <Accordion.Body className="p-0">
                <div className="options-block">
                  {Array.isArray(item["values"]) === true && (
                    <>
                      {fdata[idx]["search"] !== "" ? (
                        <>
                          {item["values"]
                            .filter(({ name }) =>
                              name
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .includes(fdata[idx]["search"].toLowerCase())
                            )
                            .map((val, ind) => (
                              <div className="form-check mt-3">
                                <input
                                  className="form-check-input"
                                  type="radio"
                                  value={val["name"]}
                                  id={`filter-${item["filter"]}${ind}`}
                                  checked={item["checkedValue"] === val["name"]}
                                  onClick={(event) =>
                                    filterOnClick(event, item["filter"], idx)
                                  }
                                />
                                <label
                                  className="form-check-label"
                                  htmlFor={`filter-${item["filter"]}${ind}`}
                                >
                                  {val["name"]}
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            ))}
                        </>
                      ) : (
                        <>
                          {item["values"].map((val, ind) => (
                            <div className="form-check mt-3">
                              <input
                                className="form-checkreload-input"
                                type="radio"
                                value={val["name"]}
                                id={`filter-${item["filter"]}${ind}`}
                                checked={item["checkedValue"] === val["name"]}
                                onClick={(event) =>
                                  filterOnClick(event, item["filter"], idx)
                                }
                              />
                              <label
                                className="form-check-label"
                                htmlFor={`filter-${item["filter"]}${ind}`}
                              >
                                {val["name"]}
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          ))}
                        </>
                      )}
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              </Accordion.Body>
            </div>
          </Accordion.Item>
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Universities;
// Universities end here

//Home.js start here
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return <p>Home page</p>;
};

export default Home;
// Home.js end here

// App.js start here
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Universities from "./Universities";
import Home from "./Home";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/universities" element={<Universities />} />
        <Route exact path="/universities/study-in-:countries-cnhp" element={<Universities />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: If you want that to persist you shouldn't be storing it in state, but in the URL and reading/writing to it (query parameters). https://github.com/pbeshai/use-query-params can help make that easier

Answer (score 2):

It's the correct behavior of react state because you can not save your datas in state and expect they be there even by browser refresh so you should save them with api in your database or you can use browser local storage to save your data in browser storage and you can use it by getting them from localStorage